# How to know the value of X on ROC curve in particular cutoff

Tags: r, glm, roc

1. I made a multiple regression with GLM
2. Made a ROC curve
3. Have optimal points of threshold, sensitivity and specifity

question: i need to know the value of X variables in a particular threshold point (edad+hor_1+hijos_viv+focos_inca+focos_ahor+renta+estim_pago+tot_hom+tot_muj+tot_hog+Rural+Propietario). Is there a way in R to get them?

```
res_reglog02 <- glm(Pobreza~edad+hor_1+hijos_viv+focos_inca+focos_ahor+renta+estim_pago+tot_hom+tot_muj+tot_hog+Rural+Propietario, family = binomial())
summary(res_reglog02)
```

```
res_reglog02roc <- roc(Pobreza,as.vector(res_reglog02$fitted.values))
plot(res_reglog02roc)
```

```
coords(res_reglog02roc, "best", "threshold")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "threshold point"?

Comment: I assume you mean the thresholds of hor_1, hijos_viv, focos_inca, focos_ahor, etc. before the fitting?

Comment: You can't. [The fitted values cannot be uniquely reversed to the original predictor values, and there is potentially an infinite number of solutions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67560/roc-and-multiroc-analysis-how-to-calculate-optimal-cutpoint/85413).